# My filter list task based on priority not function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a filter task list function based on the priority level. When the user choose low, the task list will only show the low task list only. Right now, when i choose low, it will not show anything same goes to the filter done task only. I hope someone can fix the code and teach me the actual code. Thank you so much !

```js
const taskForm = document.getElementById('taskForm');
const taskList = document.querySelector('#taskList ul');

//add task
function addTask() {
    // Check if any of the required fields are empty
    if (!title.value || !description.value || !dueDate.value || !priority.value) {
        alert('Please fill in all the required fields.');
    } else {
        const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        const description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        const dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDate').value;
        const priority = document.getElementById('priority').value;
        const status = document.getElementById('status').checked;

        const task = {
            title,
            description,
            dueDate,
            priority,
            status,
        };

        // Clear form fields
        taskForm.reset();

        // Add task to the list
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerHTML = `
            <div class="form">
                <strong> Title: ${task.title}</strong>
                <p> Description: ${task.description}</p>
                <small>Due Date: ${task.dueDate} | Priority: ${task.priority} | Status: ${task.status ? 'Done' : 'Not Done'}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="task-actions">
                <button class ="action-edit" onclick="editTask(this)">Edit</button>
                <button class="action-delete" onclick="deleteTask(this)">Delete</button>
            </div>
        `;

        taskList.appendChild(listItem);
        alert('Form submitted successfully!');
    }
}

//edit task
function editTask(button) {
    const listItem = button.closest('li');
    const title = listItem.querySelector('strong').textContent;
    const description = listItem.querySelector('p').textContent;
    const dueDate = listItem.querySelector('small').textContent.split('|')[0].trim().substring(10);
    const priority = listItem.querySelector('small').textContent.split('|')[1].trim().substring(9);
    const status = listItem.querySelector('small').textContent.split('|')[2].trim().substring(8) === 'Done';

    // Populate form with task details for editing
    document.getElementById('title').value = title;
    document.getElementById('description').value = description;
    document.getElementById('dueDate').value = dueDate;
    document.getElementById('priority').value = priority;
    document.getElementById('status').checked = status;

    // Remove the task from the list
    taskList.removeChild(listItem);
}

//delete task
function deleteTask(button) {
    const listItem = button.closest('li');
    taskList.removeChild(listItem);
}

// Filtering controls
const priorityFilter = document.getElementById('priorityFilter');
const statusFilter = document.getElementById('statusFilter');

// Initial filtering (show all tasks)
filterByPriority('');
filterByStatus(null);

// Filter functions
function filterByPriority(priorityLevel) {
    const tasks = tasklist.querySelectorAll('li');
    tasks.forEach(task => {
        const taskPriority = task.querySelector('small').textContent.split('|')[1].trim();
        if (taskPriority === priorityLevel || priorityLevel === '') {
            task.style.display = 'block';
        } 
        else {
            task.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}

function filterByStatus(isDone) {
    const tasks = tasklist.querySelectorAll('li');
    tasks.forEach(task => {
        const taskStatus = task.querySelector('small').textContent.split('|')[2].trim() === 'Done';
        if (taskStatus === isDone || isDone === null) {
            task.style.display = 'block';
        } 
        else {
            task.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}

// Add event listeners to filtering controls
priorityFilter.addEventListener('change', () => {
    filterByPriority(priorityFilter.value);
});

statusFilter.addEventListener('change', () => {
    filterByStatus(statusFilter.value === 'done');
});


//change bg colour
const button = document.getElementById('color-changer');
const body = document.body;

// Define different color schemes
const colors = {
    light: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    },
    dark: {
        backgroundColor: '#A3E2F9',
    },
};

// Initial state
let currentColorScheme = colors.light;
body.style.backgroundColor = currentColorScheme.backgroundColor;
body.style.color = currentColorScheme.textColor;

// Change color on button click
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (currentColorScheme === colors.light) {
        currentColorScheme = colors.dark;
    } 
    else {
        currentColorScheme = colors.light;
    }

    body.style.backgroundColor = currentColorScheme.backgroundColor;
    body.style.color = currentColorScheme.textColor;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="aboutUs.html">About</a>
    </div>
      
    <h2>Task Manager</h2>

    <button id="color-changer" type="color-changer">Change Background Colors</button>

    <form id="taskForm">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" required>

        <label for="message">Description:</label>
        <textarea id="description" rows="4" placeholder="Type your description here"></textarea>

        <label for="dueDate">Due Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="dueDate" required>

        <label for="priority">Priority:</label>
        <select id="priority" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Priority</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="high">High</option>
        </select>

        <div class="statusContainer" id="statusContainer">
            <label for="status">Status:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="status">
            <label for="status">Done</label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
    </form>

    <div class="task-list">

        <h2>Tasks List</h2>
        <select id="priorityFilter">
            <option value="">All Priorities</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="high">High</option>
          </select>
          
          <select id="statusFilter">
            <option value="all">All Statuses</option>
            <option value="done">Done</option>
            <option value="not-done">Not Done</option>
          </select>
          
       
        <div id="taskList">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could write the priority in to a data-attribute, so you wouldn't have to parse the text of your task html, but instead just select by attribute.

Comment: by the way your code has multiple problems... to begin with, JS is case sensitive and `taskList` is different than `tasklist`. The html also .. you have the form tag declared twice and some other invalid markup. In short, if you want to learn something, stick to simpler problems instead of mixing all together

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.